# The cursor keeps jumping to the next line automatically

Tags: vim, line, text-cursor

When I'm in insert mode and I'm typing, at some point of typing, the cursor jumps automatically to the next line. (It jump at the same point all the time, no matter if I delete the line, close document).

Answer (score 0):

Go to `~/.vimrc` and make sure you have not set any options to prevent you from typing beyond a specified column. It could also be a plugin.

Comment: I actually fixed. Was the TextWidth. I just typed `:set tw=0` and is fine now. But I don't know why it changed before; is there a shortcut for that? Maybe I could have used that shortcut accidentally.

Comment: Put this option in your vimrc.

Comment: According to the manual, 0 is the default value, I think is not necessary.

Comment: @Mike087 there is no built-in shortcut for that. The value of `:help 'textwidth'` was changed _explicitly_, either by you or by a plugin.

Comment: And from what I saw, if I set the textwidth in the terminal window and save the document; the textwidth property is also saved with the document.